# identifier expected in try catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to run a catch block but it keeps saying that an identifier is expected. Any help would be welcome. The object of this method (it is in a main so I can test it) is to get a valid value for an integer. If the value is not valid it should loop until a valid number is entered. I attempted to do this using a while loop, and the try...catch to fix any exceptions. Thank you

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NumberFormatException
    {
        String input;
        boolean x = false;
        int number;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer: ");      //creates input box for user to enter integer value
        number = Integer.parseInt(input);

        try
        {
           while (number < -2147483648 && number > 2147483647)
        {
            x = false;
            number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("You selected: " + number)
        }

        }

        catch (NumberFormatException)
        {
             input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a valid integer: ");
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not defining a name (identifier) for the `NumberFormatException` in the `catch` statement.

You need:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: this answered the question thank you very much. However now the code is still jumbled and does not quite compile like I had hoped. Any hints/suggestions for me to do? ( I don't need the answer outright but help is appreciated)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. How is the code jumbled? What you have posted doesn't look jumbled. And the code either compiles or it doesn't compile. Do you mean it doesn't behave as you had hoped?

Comment: Yes, that is a much better way of phrasing it. When I enter a value that is larger than -2147483648 and a number smaller than 2147483647, I enter the loop. Which is the opposite of what I wanted. Secondly when I enter a number that should not be valid I run across an exception error.

Comment: That's a separate question than the one you originally asked, which was regarding an identifier exception in the catch block. You need to/should post a new question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your numbers problem:
number < -2147483648 && number > 2147483647
Those are the min and max values of integer, so perhaps using long type instead of int will help.

Comment: my professor wanted us to use the min and max range of an integer, they are not inclusive so wouldn't the data still be ok as an int?